# Bootstrap into already existing html/css site

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I already have html/css website. Is it possible to insert bootstrap into it and use it only for some features , for example making this website responsive on all devices etc?

Comment: yessssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: and how is it possible please?

Comment: use from here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/ by adding the `css` and `js` files this is will affect some of your design but not much if you use bootstrap classes already

Comment: I it possible, but you need to rewrite your code to meet bootstrap rules

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

Bootstrap sets CSS properties on *many* elements. Simply adding it will create a great many side effects.

Its effects are not limited to elements that you specify.

---

It also won't magically make things responsible. The responsive features in it require specific HTML structures which you won't have.

If you want to make an existing site responsive, you are best off writing your own media queries.

Comment: So what should i do? Should i recreate my website just by using bootstrap or what?

Comment: @GOD — You could start again using Bootstrap as a base, but I'd just write my own CSS.

Comment: Yeah okay so i think i will just use my own media queries without bootstrap. Because rn my site on lower resolution looks terrible

Comment: I don't agree. You can perfectly use the grid only for responsive layouts on your site, and avoid the clashes of bootstrap styles with your existing site styles. Se my answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the responsive helper utilities and the grid, then you can import the grid only, so that bootstrap styles don't clash with you own existing styles.

So instead of importing `bootstrap.css` you just import `bootstrap-grid.css`.

If you use SCSS compiler you can do the same thing just with the .scss extension.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/contents/#css-files